# What should be the approach to avoid duplicate code in below pseudo c code snippet?

Tags: c, algorithm

```
if(var == something) {
    A();
    B();
} else if(var == something_else) {
    A();
    B();
    C();
} else {
    assert(false);
}
```

How can i avoid duplicate code of calling A() and B() in both `if` cases. Should i use switch case like,

```
switch(var) {
case something:
case something_else:
    A();
    B();
    break;
}
if (var == something_else)
   C():
```

What is the better solution? Is there any performance penalty in `switch` vs `if else`?

Comment: Does calling order matters?

Comment: Example you've given is extremely simple, and it seems that trying to minimize code reuse in this case is not worth the effort. It only makes code harder to read.

Comment: @user694733, This is just example for what i am trying to do in complex framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As calling order doesn't matter, try this:

```
switch(var) {    
    case something_else:
        C();
    case something:
        A();
        B();
    break;
    default:
        assert(false);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (var == something || var == something_else) {
    A();
    B();
}

if (var == something_else) {
    C();
}
```

If you also need the `else`, you can do this:

```
if (var == something || var == something_else) {
    A();
    B();

    if (var == something_else) {
        C();
    }
} else {
    assert(false);
}
```

In regards to your question,

> Is there any performance penalty in switch vs if else?

Please read the answers to this question:

[Is 'switch' faster than 'if'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805026/)

In short, normally there wouldn't be any noticeable difference. So you should write your code with the readability in mind. Between `if/else` and `switch`, just choose whatever is more natural.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested if statement for this, like so:

```
If (var == something || var == something_ese) {
    A();
    B();
    If (var == something_else) { C(); }
}
Else
{
    Assert(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest separating the `assert` and the work:

```
assert(var == something || var == something_else);

A();
B();
if(var == something_else) {
    C();
}
```

Not only this avoids duplication of `A` and `B` calls, but also makes it more readable as you specify the pre-requisites right at the beginning.