# If Statements not working with Strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I am practicing C++ again after a not touching it for quite some time. I was trying to write an if statement that will output different texts based on the input given. However, I keep receiving the wrong output each time...

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::string answer;

    cout << "Hello!" << '\n';
    cout << "Do you have a dog?" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "yes" || "yeah")
    {
        cout << "Thats great!";
    }
    else if (answer == "no" || "nah")
    {
        cout << "Aww, thats too bad...";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Umm, I didn't get that." << '\n';
        cout << "Could you repeat that again?" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep receiving the output of the first If Statement regardless of what I enter. Any input will display "Thats great!"

Comment: Should be `if (answer == "yes" || answer == "yeah")`

Comment: I see this question a lot more for Python than C++.

Comment: [Obligatory link to random `in` operator madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984196/compact-way-to-write-if-statement-with-many-equalities/36020725#36020725)

Comment: *"Any input will display 'Thats great!'"* Well, yeah, `"yeah"` is true...

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using condition if (answer == "yes" || "yeah") - The compiler takes it as "answer == "yes"" OR "yeah" and the second condition ("yeah) will always be true as in C++, the expression "yeah" by itself is true because it is a non empty string literal.

Use the following syntax `if (answer == "yes" || answer == "yeah")`

Comment: _""yeah" by itself is true because it is a non empty string literal"_ -- slightly confusing statement here, because it might imply that an _empty_ string literal is false, which is incorrect: `""` is just as `true` as any other string literal.

Comment: @paddy absolutely correct.  Because it isn't the literal itself that is being evaluated, it's the address (pointer) of the literal - which will never be allocated at 0.