# cleaner way to check whether or not a the current window.location.href is equal to any of the strings in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, ecmascript-6, href

Im trying to do a redirect if the url is equal to any of the strings in the following array of urls:

So I did the following

```
function redirectUser() {
  if (window.location.href === 'https://swish.com/login' || window.location.href === 'https://swish.com/register' || window.location.href === 'https://swish.com/overview') {
    window.location.replace('https://swish.com/onboard');
  }
}
```

But this is a bit ugly, so I thought of putting the urls in an array and doing something like this:

```
function redirectUser() {
  const urls = ['https://swish.com/login', 'https://swish.com/register', 'https://swish.com/overview' ]
for(let url of urls) {
  if (window.location.href === url) {
    window.location.replace('https://swish.com/onboard');
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? If not, which would be the better option in your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: `if(urls.includes(window.location.href))  redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it will help you

```
   function redirectUser() {
     const urls = ['https://swish.com/login', 'https://swish.com/register', 
      'https://swish.com/overview' ]
         if(urls.includes(window.location.href)){
         window.location.replace('https://swish.com/onboard');
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you already have all the strings statically within the code. So you can try using `switch` which performance wise is faster than `if` [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6805054). 
If you are reproducing strings via some logic, then you can also opt for **Regular Expressions** which is even faster. Else, you can stick with arrays.