# code style - How should I validate an integer against many possible values?

Tags: c++, validation, opengl, enums

I am writing a small wrapper around OpenGL so that I can use it in an object-oriented way. I have created a class called a buffer, and in its constructor I would like it to validate the type of buffer that it has been passed against lots of GLenum types. Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
Buffer::Buffer(GLenum type) {

    // Validate 'type'.
    switch (type) {
        // *** These are the valid values ***
        case GL_ARRAY_BUFFER:
        case GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER:
        case GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER:
        case GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER:
        // *** Lots more valid values here... ***
            break; // Jump out of the switch statement.

        default:
            throw std::logic_error("Invalid GLenum 'type' in Buffer constructor.");
    }

    type_ = type;
    target_ = target;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer_);

}
```

In this code, the `switch` statement would step in to the appropriate value, and pass through the other valid values until it broke out of the `switch` statement. All other values would step into the `default` clause and throw an exception. I could, however, also use an `if` statement:

```
if (type != GL_ARRAY_BUFFER &&
    type != GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER &&
    type != GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER &&
    type != GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER &&
    // *** Lots more valid values here... ***
    ) {
        throw std::logic_error("Invalid GLenum 'type' in Buffer constructor.");
    }

    // ...
}
```

However, this uses a lot of repetition of `type !=` and isn't necessarily any clearer. Is there an accepted convention when doing this, for **code clarity** and for **speed**? Should I be validating my inputs at all, when not doing so could cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: First question: can whatever function produced the `type`  value actually return an invalid value?

Comment: @NeilButterworth The `type` value is generally hard-coded in, and doesn't rely on a function -- but my classmates are going to be using this `class` and I can't rely on them to follow my documentation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97987/advantage-of-switch-over-if-else-statement  A switch is much more likely to generate efficient code, even with a 20 year old compiler.

Comment: @Olivier I guessed that the `switch` would be more efficient, but is there any difference from a code clarity perspective (especially with the intentional fallthroughs?)

Comment: Why not use `assert` instead of an exception? Using an invalid type is a bug and means that your code does not work the way you thought it did. What exactly would you intend to *do* in a `catch (std::logic_error const& exc)`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl It was to provide a more convenient debug message than `assert(false);`. I think any exceptions are just being printed to standard output.

Comment: @AlexV-P: An assertion, if not disabled with `NDEBUG`, terminates the application immediately, which is typically the best thing that can happen if a bug is detected at runtime. An exception is part of the designed program flow and should not be confused with bug detection.

Comment: @Alex I find the switch clearer as well as there is less syntax to parse to understand it. That's the kind of thing switch is meant for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a `std::set` if there are many values:

```
static std::set<int> invalidValues = 
     { GL_ARRAY_BUFFER 
     , GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER
     , GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER
     , GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER        
     // ...
     };

if(invalidValues.find(type) != invalidValues.end()) {
    throw std::logic_error("Invalid GLenum 'type' in Buffer constructor.");
}
```

This will serve for speed and better readability.

> Should I be validating my inputs at all, when not doing so could cause undefined behaviour?

You never want *undefined behavior* in your program. You can't rely this would cause an exception (crash) or such.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: If the values in the set don't need to be sorted consider using `std::unordered_set` and if you don't actually need to use the result of `std::find` consider using `std::any_of` or `std::none_of`

Comment: @YoungJohn In this case, it looks like an `std::unordered_set` and `std::none_of` are more appropriate.